# How to get rid of the Font Mapping dialog in Flash Pro CC?

Tags: flash, flash-cc

This dialog comes up every time I open the .fla file. Even though I choose a new font, it doesn't seem to be saved. I tried using the Find dialog to locate where exactly the font in question is used, but the search doesn't return any results.

[image: Font Mapping dialog]

Has anybody been able to find a solution to this? It seems that this problem has been around since at least Flash Pro CS4.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, however in flash CS6 you can go to Preferences -> Text 
and uncheck "Show for missing fonts"

Just figured others might like to know.